# bootstrap modal is not fading in/out smoothly in my app - memory leak?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, memory-leaks

I am working on an single page application with a bootstrap UI. I created a modal module in order to dynamically create modals in my app. I noticed that my modals are not fading in/out smoothly so I am worried about memory leaks.

My first idea was not to use my modal module but to trigger a bootstrap modal as they document on the website, so I copied the markup pasted on my index.html and call the bootstrap plugin like so:

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

The problem still persists. I have then opened developer tools in the 'Timeline' tab clicked on Record (the dark-grey rounded button in the top left corner), performed right click several times and clicked on 'Record' again.

Below is a screenshot on how it looks. [image]

Does that look like a bootstrap memory leak? I did the same test on bootstrap doc page, and the picture looks almost the same. But the modals are transitioning much more smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modal does have memory leak due to the fact that modal scope is re-used. Watchers are added to the scope each time it is reused. If you did a little bit of research you would have found someone here fixed the issue:

[github bootstrap modal memory leaks](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1491)

You can also check this: [Modal bootstrap singleton](https://github.com/dhilt/angular-bootstrap-modal-singleton)

Comment: that seems to be an angular plugin. I am not using angular, but thanks for the idea. I will research this topic more.

Comment: I made some further research and it seems like the smoothness has to do with this issue https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3080 I checked the timeline and there are many repaints that the browser is doing while bootstrap is fading in and out. That seems to be the problem, though I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the issue. I was trying to catch all the errors in my app in a very wrong way by surrounding the body of every method in a `try {} catch(e){}` block. While developing I thought that would be a good strategy to catch errors in my scripts (I wasn't using code linting either).

I made further research and it turns out `try {} catch(e){}` blocks can affect performance quite a lot. There are more slides, talks and jsperfs about the subject on the internet.

I replaced `try {} catch(e){}` blocks with a global method `window.onerror = function(){};` and I can notice a big difference.